# How to find and manipulate words in sentences in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

I am trying to identify words within sentences that are only made up of numbers. Once I find a word only made up of numbers, I have a certain manipulation I would like to do to it. I am able to do this manipulation to a single string of numbers, but I am absolutely at a loss of how to do so if the strings are randomly positioned across a sentence.

To do so to one string, I confirmed it was only numbers and iterated through its characters so that I skipped the first number, changed the rest to certain letter values and added a new character to the end. These specifics aren't necessarily what is important. I am trying to find a way of treating each random "word" of numbers in a sentence the same way. Is this possible?

I am not supposed to use any advanced functions. Only loops, enumerate, if chains, string functions etc. I feel like I am just overthinking something!

```html
NUM_BRAILLE="*"
digits='1234567890'
decade="abcdefhij"


def numstuff(s):
    if len(s)==1 and s.isdigit():
        s=s+NUM_BRAILLE
    elif " " not in s and s.isdigit():
        start_s=s[:1]
        s=s[1:]
        for i in s:
            if i in digits:
                s=s.replace(i,decade[int(i)-1])
        s=start_s+s+NUM_BRAILLE
   else:
   #if sentence contains many " " (spaces) how to find "words" of numbers and treat them using method above?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to extract numeric values from a sentence and pass the values to your function.

```
sentence = "This is 234 some text 888 with few words in 33343 numeric"

words = sentence.split(" ")
values= [int(word) if word.isdigit() else 0 for word in words]

print values
```

Output:
[image]